# Can't sign in when running controller tests with Devise / Rails 4 / Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, minitest

I recently installed Devise in my app to handle auth, replacing the auth system from [Michael Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/frontmatter).  It's working fine in the app itself, but I can't get my tests to auth properly, so they're pretty much all failing, which makes me sad.  I'm using Rails 4 with Minitest.

Here's an example of one of my controller tests that fails:

**learning_resources_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'
class LearningResourcesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:testuser1)
  end

  test "user can submit new resource" do
    sign_in @user # Devise helper
    post :create, {:learning_resource => {:name => "My resource"}}
    resource = assigns(:learning_resource)
    assert_redirected_to topic_path(@topic1, :learning_resource_created => "true")
  end
end
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Return true is test user is signed in
  def is_signed_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  def sign_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      # Sign in by posting to the sessions path
      post signin_path, session: {  email:       user.email,
                                    password:    password,
                                    remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      # Sign in using the session
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
    end
  end

  private

    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end

end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

**fixtures/users.yml**

```
testuser1:
  name: Test User 1
  email: testuser1@mydumbdomain.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

The assert_redirected_to in the test always fails as the redirect is the sign in page instead of the topic page.  All of my other tests fail in similar ways, indicating the user isn't signed in.  I have scoured the Devise wiki and docs, but most of them cover testing with Rspec, not Minitest.

I tried using byebug within the test after the sign_in to check out the session, and I get this:

> (byebug) session.inspect
>
> {"warden.user.user.key"=>[[336453508], ""]}

If I try to call the :create, I get this error:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `ActionDispatch::Response#to_ary` no longer
>   performs implicit conversion to an array. Please use `response.to_a`
>   instead, or a splat like `status, headers, body = *response`. (called
>   from puts at
>   /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/forwardable.rb:183)
>   302 {"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1;
>   mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff",
>   "Location"=>"http://test.host/signup",
>   "Set-Cookie"=>"request_method=POST; path=/",
>   "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is with hash

```
post :create, {:learning_resource => {:name => "My resource"}}
```

Try

```
post :create, :learning_resource => {:name => "My resource"}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything.  That syntax used to work before switching to Devise, so I'm pretty sure it's valid.